# hyperref and titletoc: prints extra "section.1" or "Doc-Startchapter.1"

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, titlesec, titletoc

I'm using both [hyperref](https://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) and [titletoc](https://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) for writing my thesis, which is known to cause [other kind of incompatibilities](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56023/titlesec-messin-up-my-hyperrefd-table-of-contents/56025) which I don't observe in my case.

Using `titletoc` I'm adding a table of content at the beginning of each chapter but an unwanted string is printed before each of these ToC:

```
Doc-Startchapter*.7chapter*.8chapter.1section.1.1section*.9section*.9figure.captio
```

Here you are MWE where an unwanted `section.1` appears (I added one subsection for making the actual ToC appear, but it is actually not needed for reproducing the problem):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\begin{document}

\section{Bla}

\startcontents
\printcontents{}{2}{}

\subsection{Blabla: bla bla}

\end{document}
```

Note the `section.1` string in the picture:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Load hyperref after titletoc:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{Bla}

\startcontents
\printcontents{}{2}{}

\subsection{Blabla: bla bla}

\end{document}
```